# Is there a new Java 8 way of retrieving the file extension?

Tags: java, file, file-extension

What I did up until now is following:

```
String fileName = "file.date.txt";
String ext = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);

System.out.printf("'%s'%n", ext); // prints: 'txt'
```

Is there a more convenient way in Java 8?

Comment: The importance of a file extension is often overestimated. The `substring`/`lastIndexOf` solution is sufficient.

Comment: Java can not provide you with explicit means for getting the "file extension" of a path name because the concept of a file extension is not portable. Unix does not really have them (you can have a `.` near the end of a file leaf name, but the O/S kernel does not consider what follows to be significant).

Comment: Uhm. Extensions are a convenient and very common way of organizing files, used by a vast number of tools and applications, even if modern operating systems do not handle them explicitly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, see the [changelog of the JDK8 release](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8-whats-new-2157071.html)

Comment: The changes made to java.io resp. java.nio are summarized here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/io/enhancements.html#jdk8

Comment: If this is an answer, I was expecting it to have some more context. :) as the one mentioned by @Pshemo much better and helpful.

Answer (score 17):

No there is no more efficient/convenient way in JDK, but many libraries give you ready methods for this, like Guava: [`Files.getFileExtension(fileName)`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/io/Files.html#getFileExtension-java.lang.String-) which wraps your code in single method (with additional validation).

Answer (score 13):

Not Java8, but you can always use [`FilenameUtils.getExtension()`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.html#getExtension%28java.lang.String%29) from apache Commons library. :)

Answer (score 2):

Actually there *is* a new way of thinking about returning file extensions in Java 8.

Most of the "old" methods described in the other answers return an empty string if there is no extension, but while this avoids NullPointerExceptions, it makes it easy to forget that not all files have an extension. By returning an [Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html), you can remind yourself and others about this fact, and you can also make a distinction between file names with an empty extension (dot at the end) and files without extension (no dot in the file name)

```
public static Optional<String> findExtension(String fileName) {
    int lastIndex = fileName.lastIndexOf('.');
    if (lastIndex == -1) {
        return Optional.empty();
    }
    return Optional.of(fileName.substring(lastIndex + 1));
}
```

Comment: `Optional.of(fileName).filter(value -> value.contains(".")).map(value -> value.substring(value.lastIndexOf('.')));`

Comment: What about this example `/tmp/my.directory/test_file`?

Answer (score 2):

Use `FilenameUtils.getExtension` from **Apache Commons IO**

Example:

You can provide **full path name** or **only the file name**.

```
String myString1 = FilenameUtils.getExtension("helloworld.exe"); // returns "exe"
String myString2 = FilenameUtils.getExtension("/home/abc/yey.xls"); // returns "xls"
```

Hope this helps ..

Comment: There is an almost three year old answer mentioning this. There is no need to write that again.