# Adding an infix between file name and extension using java 8

Tags: java, path, java-8

In my code, I would like to transform a path of the form

```
/a/path/to/a/file/image.jpg
```

to

```
/a/path/to/a/file/image_resized.jpg
```

Currently, I am using the the following code which uses `FilenameUtils` from apache commons IO.

```
public Path resize(Path original) {
    String baseName = FilenameUtils.getBaseName(original.toString());
    String extension = FilenameUtils.getExtension(original.toString());
    return Paths.get(original.getParent().toString(), baseName + "_resized." + extension);
}
```

I was wondering if some of this code could be enhanced using java 8 features, specifically:

- is there a java-8 way for extracting the extension and basename, without using a dependency on Apache Commons IO (FilenameUtils), and without regex (I prefer dependency on apache commons IO over using a regex here)
- joining to Paths without `toString()` in `Paths.get(existingPath.toString(), "path/to/append");`

The second part of the question is answered in [Combine paths in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/412380/combine-paths-in-java)

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30913799/is-there-a-new-java-8-way-of-retrieving-the-file-extension

Comment: It seems there is no new way to extract extension in Java 8 (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30913799/is-there-a-new-java-8-way-of-retrieving-the-file-extension)

Comment: indeed, that pretty much answers it

Comment: And avoiding the .toString() in my question above, or better said, joining two Paths, can be done using `existingPath.resolve("path/to/append");` - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/412380/combine-paths-in-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this? you can use [Path#resolveSibling(String)](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#resolveSibling-java.lang.String-) to get the path relative to the `original` path. and use the [Path#getFileName](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#getFileName--) to get the filename in path.

thanks to @Holger point out that I can use the regex `"(.*?)(\\.[^.]+)?$"` instead.

```
public Path resize(Path original) {
    return original.resolveSibling(original.getFileName().toString()
            //               v--- baseName 
            .replaceFirst("(.*?)(\\.[^.]+)?$", "$1_resized$2"));
            //                      ^--- extension            
}
```

### Output

```
//            v---for printing, I used the `String` here,actually is Paths.get(...)
resize("/a/b/image.jpg") =>  "/a/b/image_resized.jpg";

resize("/a/b/image.1.jpg") => "/a/b/image.1_resized.jpg";

resize("/a/b/image1") => "/a/b/image1_resized";
```

Comment: I like the resolveSibling, but find the regex a bit heavy to read. I combined your resolveSibling with a solution using lastIndexOf instead, as a new answer.

Comment: @StijnHaezebrouck you shouldn't worry about the regex, because the filename is shorter and it is  closed to use `lastIndexOf`. And use the regex can make the rest of work easily.

Comment: What does `(?=.*?)` mean? A positive look-ahead that accepts anything? Looks entirely obsolete to me. Besides that, why so complicated? Why not just `.replaceFirst("(\\.[^.]+)?$", "_resized$1")`? Or, if you want to care for even the smallest bits of performance, `.replaceFirst("(?:\\.[^.]++)?$", "_resized$0")`

Comment: @Holger sir, thanks for the feedback. :), my intention is makes the 2 parts `baseName` & `.extension` clearly by use 2  look-aheads. can I do it like that?

Comment: No, these lookaheads are called [zero-width lookahead](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#special), because they do not advance the text position, in other words, if you place one lookahead after another, both are applied to the same position. If you want to match both parts, just don’t use lookaheads `.replaceFirst("(.*?)(\\.[^.]+)?$", "$1_resized$2")`

Comment: @Holger thanks very much sir. " *if you place one lookahead after another, both are applied to the same position.* " - could you give me a min example?

Comment: When you search for `(?=[0-5])(?=[5-9]).`, both lookaheads and the dot are applied to the same position, so it will match occurrences of `5` and nothing else.

Comment: @Holger yeah. I can produce the problem of the `(?=[0-5])(?=[5-9])`, but I can't produce the problem of my regex, I think the trick thing is it has a `\\.` between them, Am I right?

Comment: As said in my first comment, `(?=.*?)` matches *anything*, therefore, is entirely obsolete. It doesn’t matter that it doesn’t match from start to the dot, as you thought, but from the dot to the end instead. `.*?` will always be fulfilled, regardless of where it is applied. And it doesn’t advance the match position. In other words, it has no effect. You can remove it, and the result doesn’t change. `(\\.[^.]+)?$` is already sufficient to match an extension (or the end position if there is no dot). Using a lookahead like your `(?=\\.[^.]+)?$` will match the position before the extension.

Comment: @Holger I'm sorry, sir. I have forgot the previous context, :(. thanks for your advice.

Comment: @Holger After read your comments again and again, I found I misread the word **obsolete** ago. Eventually, I found you mean that it is  **redundant**, :( ... thanks very much, sir. let me learn more and more.

Comment: Using named regex makes the regex perhaps easier to read, but is little more verbose: `.replaceFirst("(?<baseName>.*?)(?<extension>\\.[^.]+)?$", "${baseName}_resized${extension}"));`

Answer (score 5):

You don't need a library for *such a small and simple task* IMO (and no java-8 does not add support for that); and I also can't tell why a regex is out of the question

```
    int where = input.lastIndexOf(".");

    String result = input.substring(0, where) + "_resized" + input.substring(where);
    System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: the most simple answer

Comment: I did not want to use a regex if there is a specific method for it in java8. As there isn't, I still prefer you lastIndexOf as it is somewhat more simple then a regex.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure that Java8 doesn't have anything to deal with this. Maybe you can checkout the Files API from Guava.`Files.getFileExtension(fileName)`

Comment: it would replace one dependency with another, but useful if Guava is already in your classpath for other uses.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved by using simple string operations, you don't need libraries for stuff like this. One of the solution to this problem is -

```
class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
     String path = "/a/path/to/a/file/image.jpg";
     String[] temp = path.split("/");
     String[] tmp = temp[temp.length - 1].split("\\.");
     tmp[0] = tmp[0] + "-resized";
     String fullname = String.join(".", tmp);
     temp[temp.length - 1] = fullname;
     String newPath =  String.join("/", temp);
     System.out.print(newPath);

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I combine your answers into this one:

First, there seem to be no way of java build in way of extracting the file name extension in java ([other stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30913799/is-there-a-new-java-8-way-of-retrieving-the-file-extension))

Then using the `String.lastIndexOf()` is a simple reliable manner to get the extension (Eugene). Finally using `Path.resolveSibling()` (holi-java) joins the new filename with the parent path.

resulting code:

```
public Path resize(Path original) {
    String fileName = original.getFileName().toString();
    int extIndex = fileName.lastIndexOf(".");
    String baseName = fileName.substring(0,extIndex);
    String extension = fileName.substring(extIndex);
    return original.resolveSibling(baseName+"_resized"+extension);
}
```

Comment: First, upvote. As you can see your code is increased. And don't support filename without extension.

Comment: I have already upvoted your answer, and indeed, the code is much more verbose.